# Correct way to drag a UIView around with a pan gesture with a UIDynamicAnimator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a simple game that I'm starting to make that has a ball bouncing around and I want the user to be able to drag a paddle around and hit the ball. The ball is bouncing around perfectly well, but the paddle behavior isn't working properly.

In the function `start` the paddle is created and then an attachment behavior is setup and a `PanGestureRecogniser` is declared:

```
self.attach = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.paddle attachedToAnchor:self.paddle.center];
self.attach.damping = 1.0;

SEL drag_sel = NSSelectorFromString(@"drag:");

self.paddle.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:drag_sel];

[self.paddle addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```

The `panGestureRecognizer` looks like this:

```
- (void)drag :(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)pan {

    CGPoint p = [pan translationInView:self.hockeyView];
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", p.x, p.y);

    UIView *targetView = pan.view;
    self.attach.anchorPoint = p;

    if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        [self.animator addBehavior:self.attach];
    }
    else if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        [self.animator removeBehavior:self.attach];
    } 
}
```

I can move the paddle around but it doesn't follow my finger, and the collisions with the ball don't look like they did before I added the ability to move the paddle. I'd be grateful for some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add and remove the behavior with each gesture, just add it once, then move the `anchorPoint`. The animation will need some time to run after your gesture recognizer hits `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`.

If you really want to remove the behavior, implement `UIDynamicAnimatorDelegate` and wait for the  `dynamicAnimatorDidPause` message.